# Node.js http.request append header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous

Hi I am piping readable stream `X` into the `var req = http.request object`.
The thing is I want to append some header after I read some data from `X`.

Can I append headers to `req` object after its creation (headers are given in  option parameter to `http.request(options, callback)` function.

I want to do asynchronously so each read from `X` thats why I cannot send header in option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok It seems I've found a solution. Since `http.request` returns a `http.clientRequest` object which has `setHeader(name, value)` method, you can use it after you create request.

*Now I think It was a nooby question, moderators its up to you to decide what to do with it.*